# Is $\underset{i\in\mathcal{I}}{\text{arg max}\,\,} f_i(x)$ a notation abuse?

Tags: optimization, notation

Let $\mathcal{I} = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be the index set of all my functions (so I have $n$ many functions). For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, find $i$ that solves:
$$
\underset{i\in\mathcal{I}}{\text{arg max}\,\,} f_i(x)
$$

So, $i$ is not the *argument* of function $f_i$. Instead, $i$ is the *index* of function $f_i$. E.g. we have functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$, and our goal is to find the *index* of the function that achieves maximum value when given input $x$.

But my problem is that $i$ is really not an "argument". Or is it? I think "arg max" implis that I'm returning the *argument* of a function that maximizes it.

But I'm clearly not returning the argument. In fact, the argument is constant at $x$. Instead, I'm returning the *index of a function* that is maximum for the input $x$.

Therefore, **Question 1:** should I do it this way, instead?
$$
\underset{i\in\mathcal{I}}{\text{function index max}\,\,} f_i(x)
$$

Comment: Does the max always exist? Since you notify $i \in \mathbb N$, which means you have countably infinitely many functions, right?

Comment: @YujieZha Yes, sorry. I changed $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{I} = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ instead. I hope it's better now.

Comment: No, it isn't an abuse of notation. it's clear what you mean. $(i,x)\mapsto f_i(x)$ is just as good a function on $\mathbb{I}\times \mathbb{R}$ as each $f_i$ is on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's fine to keep $i\in\mathbb N$ too; after all, nobody has a problem with $\arg\max_{x\in\mathbb R}$ either.

Comment: If you have to ask, it probably is. In all seriousness, though, it probably wouldn't hurt to have explanatory words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{argmax}_i f_i(x)$ is no more an abuse of notation than $\operatorname{argmax}_x g(x)$. (I'm omitting the domain of the variable for simplicity; this should cause no confusion)

The point is that *neither* $f_i(x)$ nor $g(x)$ are functions, or even formulas expressing functions: they are formulas for *numbers*. For example, $f_i(x)$ is a formula expressing a number that depends on the variables $f$, $i$, and $x$.

(for simplicity of language, I'm assuming all functions here are number-valued; this is by no means essential)

There isn't any fundamental difference between the presence of $i$ in $f_i(x)$ and the presence of $x$ in $g(x)$; in both cases, the subscript on $\operatorname{argmax}$ means to abstract its given formula as a function in the indicated variable.

For example, $\operatorname{argmax}_x g(x)$ means $\operatorname{argmax}(g)$, where the where the latter use of $\operatorname{argmax}$ is meant as an operator on functions.

Similarly, if we define a family of functions $h_x$ by $h_x(y) = f_y(x)$, then $\operatorname{argmax}_i f_i(x)$ means the same thing as $\operatorname{argmax}(h_x)$